# Determine when Visual Studio has entered design mode VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, add-in, designmode

I am trying to create an add-in in Visual Studio 2012 that will perform operations after a program has been executed. This requires me to know when design mode has been entered. I have the code below that works but it is in C#, and I am working in VB.NET.

```
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        //Initialize event handlers for host
        _debuggerEvents = _applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents;
        _debuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode += new _dispDebuggerEvents_OnEnterDesignModeEventHandler(OnEnterDesignMode);
    }

    /// <summary>Handles when the host application object's debugger enters design mode (is done debugging).</summary>
    /// <param name="reason">The reason that the host application object is entering design mode.</param>
    public static void OnEnterDesignMode(dbgEventReason reason)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ADD-IN DEBUG: Debugger enters design mode.");
    }
```

I tried converting it to its VB equivalent which resulted in

```
Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
    .
    .
    .
    ' Initialize event handlers for host
    _debuggerEvents = _hostAppObj.Events.DebuggerEvents
    _debuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode += New _dispDebuggerEvents_OnEnterDesignModeEventHandler(AddressOf _debuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode)
End Sub

Public Sub OnEnterDesignMode(ByVal reason As dbgEventReason)
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ADD-IN DEBUG: Debugger enters design mode.")
End Sub
```

Visual Studio has marked both occurrences of "_debuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode" with a note "Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur." I don't see any runtime errors, but I never see the message box pop up with the notification that design mode has been entered like the C# version does. Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `AddHandler` instead of using the `+=` method of assigning an eventhandler.

Comment: I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) statement to add an event handler (this is one of the ways how it is done in VB.NET).

In your case, this would be:

```
Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection

   ' Initialize event handlers for host
    _debuggerEvents = _hostAppObj.Events.DebuggerEvents
    AddHandler _debuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode, AddressOf OnEnterDesignMode
End Sub

Public Sub OnEnterDesignMode(ByVal reason As dbgEventReason)
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ADD-IN DEBUG: Debugger enters design mode.")
End Sub
```